# error returning and reading lambda function from python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

good afternoon,

I have a few days ago problems to return and read data from a lambda function of aws, to a python script. but I can't find the solution. I would appreciate any help. I know the error is because you are interpreting it as a string, but I did not reach the solution.
Also try using ast.literal_eval with the same result.

thanks,

def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
respuesta_servicio='{"bool_respuesta": 1, "resultado": [{"errors":"Fecha de emision La fecha del documento debe ser la fecha de HOY","codigo":21}], "error": "Fecha de emision La fecha del documento debe ser la fecha de HOY"}'

return respuesta_servicio
```

def invoke_lambda_envia(json1):

```
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name=xxxx)
client = boto3.client('lambda',xxxxxxxxx)
payload3=json1
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='vvvvvvvv',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    Payload=payload3)

respuestaServicio= response['Payload'].read().decode('utf-8')
return (respuestaServicio)
```

def finally():

```
respuestaServ=json.loads( enviar.invoke_lambda_envia(bytes(json_result, 'utf8')) )

os.system("echo main data Guia typo-python : '{}'".format( respuestaServ["resultado"][0]["errors"] ))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Which line throws the error? And what is  json1 in `payload3=json1`? Its not defined anywhere.

Comment: json1, is a json file that is passed as a parameter, I don't include it because the service responds well.